# google test functions setup() and teardown() is called for each test case or for the whole testsuit

Tags: c++, googletest

I am using google test and trying to write test fixtures to test source code, in the test fixture, there are several test cases defined.

There are `SetUp()` and `TearDown(`) functions, for those functions, if there are defined, will they be called for each test case or only once for the whole test suit?

Comment: Did you read the [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#Should_I_use_the_constructor/destructor_of_the_test_fixture_or_t)?

Comment: I read the google test document, can not find any info regarding to this

Comment: SetUpTestCase and TearDownTestCase are called before/after ALL tests of a given fixture. SetUp and TearDown are called before/after each test, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every test case have it's own fixture, so these are called every time.

Answer (score 2):

Googletest does not reuse the same test fixture object across multiple tests. For each TEST_F, googletest will create a fresh test fixture object, immediately call `SetUp()`, run the test body, call `TearDown()`, and then delete the test fixture object. [Source](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#should-i-use-the-constructordestructor-of-the-test-fixture-or-the-set-uptear-down-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can verify they are called for each test by simply adding cout statements:

in `SetUp()`:

```
cout << "SetUp called\n";
```

in `TearDown()`:

```
cout << "TearDown called\n";
```

Run your tests and look at the output; then you can see if it is called per test or per suite.